# Angular material md-card can't find its width?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I used `md-card`,but it can't find the width.When words were too much ,overflow the line.

```
Here my code:

 <md-card-title style="padding: 2px 8px;" ng-click="showServerDialog(item)" title="CPU load：{{item.loadCPU}}&#10;{{(item.usedMem)*100|number:2}}%&#10;{{item.usedDisk|filterOutput}}">
    <md-card-title-text style="height: 60px;">
        <span class="md-headline" style="font-size:16px;line-height: 32px">{{item.serverName}}</span>
        <span style="font-size: 12px;color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);" >{{item.serverUp == 1 ? 'on' : 'off'}} | {{item.loadCPU}} | {{(item.usedMem)*100|number:2}}%|{{item.usedDisk|filterOutput}}</span>
     </md-card-title-text>
 </md-card-title>
```

I try this this `<span style="font-size: 12px;color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;" >`but it not working.
If words too many ,it is a problem.

Comment: what is the text you want to display?

Comment: When words too much, I think display like ellipsis@Sajeetharan

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jVvJJq

You can see `<h3>8888888888888888888888833333333333333333333399999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999</h3>`Display incomplete.Can you help me to fix it.Two lines show is OK